# Any available third-party firmware for Linksys WAG120N?

Tags: router, firmware

Is there any custom (third-party) firmware for Linksys WAG120N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't. I was unable to find it in lists of supported devices for major firmware projects.

You can always go to DD-WRT or OpenWRT forums and ask there. Maybe you'll be lucky and someone is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information regarding the Linksys WAG120N either. Not by rooter, openwrt or dd-wrt that is ready to be used. Best is to look into the image builder and build your own firmware image for that infrastructure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: It is a bit technical but on the OpenWRT website, go to their documentation and look at the Image Builder documentation where they give instructions on building/compiling your own firmware image for a specific architecture.